# Error when generating service interface from wsdl using svcutil

Tags: wcf, soap, svcutil.exe

I'm trying to run the following command line but get an error. You can try to run the command yourself to test it, but i have placed the error i'm getting below.

```
svcutil /noConfig /language:C# /out:ICatalog.cs /n:*,ogc.csw.ebrim http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl
```

I tried downloading the wsdl and modifying it a few different ways to get it work. But i haven't been able to find out what to modify to get it to work.

```
svcutil /noConfig /language:C# /out:ICatalog.cs /n:*,ogc.csw.ebrim http://localhost/temp/csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl
```

**Does anyone know what i can modify to get this to generate code?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error i get is:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl

If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata pu
blishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.mic
rosoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.


WS-Metadata Exchange Error
    URI: http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl

    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/csw-e
brim-interface.wsdl'.

    The content type text/xml of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charse
t=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes
of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsd:description
  targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0/wsdl"
  xmlns:tns="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0/wsdl"
  xmlns:wrs="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0"
  xmlns:iri="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0/iri"
  xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2"
  xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
  xmlns:wsd="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl"
  xmlns:wsdx="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl-extensions"
  xmlns:wsoap="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/soap"
  xmlns:whttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/http"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl http://www.w3.org/2007/06/wsdl/wsdl20.xsd
  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">

  <wsd:documentation>
  W3C WSDL interface descriptions for the CSW-ebRIM 1.0 catalogue service. This
  document shall be imported by all instance-specific service descriptions.
  </wsd:documentation>

  <w'.


HTTP GET Error
    URI: http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl

    The document at the url http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl was not reco
gnized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be <schema> and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.
org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/wsdl/2.0/
csw-ebrim-interface.wsdl could not be found.'.
  - The document format is not recognized.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (2, 2).'.
  - <description xmlns='http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl'> was not expected.
```

Comment: Have you tried resolving the schema errors you see mentioned after the "HTTP GET Error" section in the error message you posted? It seems that the WSDL file is badly-formed.

Comment: yeah but it's error after error after error for instance, i remove "description xmlns='http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl" and i get another similar error, but not sure if i can just remove it.